# ZetCode PyQt4 tutorial First examples

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I am going through the ZetCode tutorial (http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/firstprograms/), but the things that supposed to happen are not happening. For instance, I do not see a "no icon" icon on the top right of my window after running the first code, nor do I see a "web.png" icon after running the second code... I assume the reason for not working could be because the tutorials were made in late 2011, is there a quick fix (like import oldQt)? Using Ubuntu 14.04, Qt 4.8.5

Cheers.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt4 tutorial 

This example shows an icon
in the titlebar of the window.

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: October 2011
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('web.png'))        

        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `print os.path.exists('web.png')`?

Comment: Yes (or should I say True)...

Comment: There's no reason why that example shouldn't work. It works as expected for me on Linux (but I'm not using ubuntu). Try changing `QWidget` to `QLabel`, and add the line `self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('web.png'))` to `initUI()`: does this display the image?

Comment: Yes, that displays the image, but not where it should display it. I just assume it's Ubuntu. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does it still happen if you rename the script?  Ubuntu has some weird caching behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 'web.png' icon is not found.
Just replace 'web.png' with the complete path and filename of an existing icon and the example will work fine.

I've tested it ok with Ubunto.

See also the thread below:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25850

Comment: It was already established in the comments to the question that the relative path works and the image can be displayed in a label. The problem is most likely caused by some ubuntu-specific setting that prevents application icons being changed.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's just the version of Ubuntu. It should work on 11.x